# How to enable run-time type information in Catia CAA?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, rtti, catia, caa

While developing a plug-in for Catia using the CAA C++-Interface, I need to do a dynamic_cast:

```
DerivedClass *derived = dynamic_cast<*derived>(base);
```

When `Build with mkmk`, the compiler gives the warning:

```
[MkMk] warning C4541: 'dynamic_cast' used on polymorphic type '<DerivedClass>' with /GR-; unpredictable behavior may result
```

I tried to enable the run-time type information by adding `LOCAL_CCFLAGS = /GR` to the `Imakefile.mk` of the module. But the compiler overwrites this flag and disables the RTTI:

```
[MkMk] Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/GR' with '/GR-'
[MkMk] warning C4541: 'dynamic_cast' used on polymorphic type '<DerivedClass>' with /GR-; unpredictable behavior may result
```

How do I enable the RTTI correctly?

Comment: I've seen in some places a LOCAL_POST_CCFLAGS. Naming seems to suggest the flags at the end, hence overriding the mkmk ones. I cannot try it however. For example https://github.com/weltermann17/just-like-java/blob/master/JLJio.m/Imakefile.mk.